# C# Socket Programming

Tags: c#, sockets

What is equivalent of these two php functions?

```
socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)  

socket_read($socketResource, $Port)
```

Comment: have you tried googling?

Comment: @GazWinter yes, but I just started the c# programming and really don't what should I search for it...

Comment: Well i have posted a couple of links below to get you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examples:
1)

```
    Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

2)

```
    s.Connect(host, port)
```

for more knowledge please use the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/attbb8f5

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [.Net Socket class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Read through this. Hope it helps.

[c# Socket Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following resources:

[How to create a socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w48w47c.aspx)

[Socket Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx)

Hope they are useful.